# What happens when I change a variable in a factory function? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop

the following factory function has `on = false`.

```
function Radio(mode) {
  let on = false;

  return {
    mode: mode,
    turnOn: function () {
      on = true;
    },
    isOn: function () {
      return on;
    }
  };
}
```

If I created an object using this factory function and used the function `fmRadio.turnOn();` inside it to change the value of `on` to be `true` like in the following lines..

```
let fmRadio = Radio('fm');

fmRadio.turnOn();
```

The output of `fmRadio.isOn();` will be `on = true`

So, Where does `on` variable change? I mean it's not part of the `fmRadio` object created..if we tried to call it it will return undefined

```
fmRadio.on;
//undefined
```

Does it change the value of `on` in the original factory function?

Answer (score 1):

Variable `on` exists only on the scope of the `function`. When you are trying to access the `on` variable, that `on` variable is not exposed for usage outside the function as the function is returning only the object with `mode, turnOn and turnOff`. You can think of this variable (on) as its a private declard variable and it doesn't have any access from outside of the class (of course it's not like that since here you have a function, but to give you an example). If you return the `on` variable from the function, you will have access on that variable using `ObjectName.on`

what you can do is

```
function Radio(mode) {
  let on = "test";

  return {
    getOn: function() { 
        return on;
    },
    setOn: function(value) { 
        on = value;
    },
    mode: mode,
    turnOn: function () {
      on = true;
    },
    isOn: function () {
      return on;
    }
  };
}
```

in this case I think you can understand it better, I created two other functions, one of the functions to get the value of variable `on` the other one to set the value, same like getters and setters in java or c#.

now if you get the value of variable on via function getOn, the value "test" will be returned, but if you set it to another value via setOn function the variable `on` will be set to the new value and next time you get the updated value. This helps if you want to keep variables read only e.g

Comment: as far as I understood, `on` is like a part of the object created but it can't be accessed by this object until the inner function is invoked. is that right?

Comment: I've updated the answer once again to make it more clear, yes it is a part of the object because the function contains a declaration, but is not returned from that function (meaning is not exposed for usage outside of that function)